# Flutter Push Notification

Tags: flutter, dart

I am a beginner in Flutter. When I tried to make IOS Push Notification in my app using cloud functions. I don't why I don't get any Push Notifications in my IOS device. This is the file which is was used in my code for notifications. [file](https://github.com/ConnectyCube/connectycube-flutter-samples/blob/master/chat_sample/lib/src/push_notifications_manager.dart)
It works fine for Android but didn't work in IOS.
main.dart file

```
void main() async => {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(),
      if (Platform.isAndroid)
        {
          await Firebase.initializeApp(),
        },
      SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp])
          .then(
        (_) {
          runApp(new MyApp());
        },
      )
    };

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Splash(),
      theme: ThemeData(accentColor: Colors.black38),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure your app has to initialize Firebase, even if the app is running on iOS. Right now, you have restricted it to Android only.

```
if (Platform.isAndroid) // <<==
{
  await Firebase.initializeApp(),
},
```

By the way, why are there commas at the end of each line? Is that a copy/paste error?

This is what it should look like if you want it Android and iOS specific:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  if (Platform.isAndroid || Platform.isIOS) {
     await Firebase.initializeApp();
  }
      
  await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);

  runApp(new MyApp());
}
```

Comment: It didn't working properly

Comment: You seem to be under the impression that it will "just work". I'm afraid I have no idea what you did so far. Look at this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@jun.chenying/flutter-tutorial-part3-push-notification-with-firebase-cloud-messaging-fcm-2fbdd84d3a5e) for an example of what you have to do. It's not all code. It's a lot of configuration.

Comment: Showing exception
MissingPluginException (MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method Firebase#initializeCore on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_core))