# Initialised Firebase for IOS AND ANDROID in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using firebase in my fluter App for Push Notification. For Android I am using this method for initialising the firebase. In Android it works fine. I can't understand how it implement for IOS.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'splash.dart';

void main() async => {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(),
      if (Platform.isAndroid)
        {
          await Firebase.initializeApp(),
        },
      SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp])
          .then(
        (_) {
          runApp(new MyApp());
        },
      )
    };

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Splash(),
      theme: ThemeData(accentColor: Colors.black38),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter Push Notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69797497/flutter-push-notification)

Comment: Yes, but It is not working properly.

Comment: Well, please don't just repost your question verbatim. If you have made some progress, post what progress you made. If you have not, at least post which step you are on. Just reposting this code piece the next day is not going to have any better results then yesterday.

Comment: oki, i understand

Comment: So how I initialised please suggest me

Comment: I did, on yesterdays question. if you don't tell us, what you did so far, we cannot help you. Again, it's not only code. It's configuration. Did you do any of that?